# homework: how to invoke a java method

Tags: java, class

I have:

```
/*
 * File: NameSurferEntry.java
 * --------------------------
 * This class represents a single entry in the database.  Each
 * NameSurferEntry contains a name and a list giving the popularity
 * of that name for each decade stretching back to 1900.
 */

import acm.util.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NameSurferEntry implements NameSurferConstants {

/* Constructor: NameSurferEntry(line) */
/**
 * Creates a new NameSurferEntry from a data line as it appears
 * in the data file.  Each line begins with the name, which is
 * followed by integers giving the rank of that name for each
 * decade.
 */
    public NameSurferEntry(String line) {
        findName(line);
        findDecades(line);
    }
...
```

as a class.

How would I call the method NameSurferEntry from within another class.

Comment: Well, thank you for tagging the question appropriately, but next time use a more descriptive title ;)

Comment: And in addition, you're going to want the calling class to be in the same folder as your NameSurferEntry class.

Answer (score 3):

NameSurferEntry is a constructor, not a method. Creating a non-default constructor will hide the default empty constructor. So

```
// asume line to be a string containing a line
NameSurferEntry entry = new NameSurferEntry(line);
```

will be the only way to create NameSurferEntry objects.

Answer (score 2):

This method is a constructor -- it gets called when you create a new `NameSurferEntry` object and pass a `String`.  You'd call it like this:

```
NameSurferEntry entry = new NameSurferEntry("some string");
```

You can tell it's a constructor because the return type is the same as the class name, and there's no method name.  It's only callable when you're creating a new `NameSurferEntry`.

Answer (score 1):

NameSurferEntry is the constructor of that class, which means it will be called every time you create a new instance of NameSurferEntry with the **new** operator.  There is no other way to call this method.

Answer (score 1):

NameSurferEntry is the constructor of the class, so you'd do something like:

```
NameSurferEntry myObject = new NameSurferEntry("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a constructor.  You'd call it in the following form:

```
NameSurferEntry newEntry = new NameSurferEntry("string goes here.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for before.  I saw a phantom void in the constructor.  as everyone else has pointed out, it should be

```
NameSurferEntry nsf = new NameSurferEntry(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to call a constructor from another constructor. 
See also this answer: [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

And, if you subclass your class, you can call it from the constructor in the subclass via a 
call to *super()*.