# how to pass a self-reference to constructors in java?

Tags: java, oop, reference

i have a class A that needs to instantiate a second class B, whose constructor needs a reference to the same object of class A...

would look like:

```
public class A {
    B b;

    public A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }
}

public class B {
    A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

well - eclipse keeps complaining that this isnt possible. i assume, this is because the reference of class A isnt "ready" yet at this moment...?
but the error wont go away if i move the init of class B to a seperate function within A wich i would call from "outside"...

how can i pass this self-reference from outside to the constructor of B?

Comment: how does it complain? My eclipse doesn't

Comment: 0
 

My javac (Sun 1.6) accepts this code, both in Java 5 and in Java 6 mode. Is Eclipse giving you a warning (yellow) or an error (red)? What is the precise message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be very careful, because until A is constructed, it doesn't really exist.  If B were to call a method on A, the program should fail because you can't call a method on A prior to A being constructed.  Construction is not complete until A fully returns from its constructor code.

If you must initialize B with A whenever A is constructed, it is much better to make a factory class for A which guarantees that B is initialized after A is constructed.  It would look something like this

```
public class AFactory {

  public A newA() {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B(a);
    return a;
  }

}
```

For this to work properly 100%, you might need to limit the visibility of the A() constructor.  I personally would put `AFactory` into the same package as `A` and make the access "default" or "package private like so

```
package same.as.afactory;

public class A {
  A() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Otherwise, B could do bad things with A not being fully constructed.

Answer (score 5):

I'd ask myself: Are you sure that's the design you want? And, if it is, would it make sense for one of those classes to be an inner class of the other?

Answer (score 2):

Look, here is a way to use a constructed self instance in the constructer itself:

```
public class Foo {
    private int x;

    public Foo() {
        this(1);
        // the self instance should have been constructed now
    }

     public Foo(int x) {
        this.x = x;
     }
}
```

[How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Create a holder object which you can pass from A to B, and then insert the this instance of A into when the A constructor is finished.  Then B can refer to the this-value inside the holder later.