# java this(null)

Tags: java, this

I want to know what does this means?

```
public Settings() {
    this(null);
}
```

The above code is the constructor of a class "Settings". What does this(null) means here?

Comment: Need more context. Is that in a class definition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what type of java constructors are these? Constructor chaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204560/what-type-of-java-constructors-are-these-constructor-chaining)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public Settings() {
    this(null); //this is calling the next constructor
}
public Settings(Object o) {
//  this one
}
```

This is often used to pass default values so you can decide to use one constructor or another..

```
public Person() {
    this("Name"); 
}
public Person(String name) {
    this(name,20)
}
public Person(String name, int age) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

It means you are calling an overloaded constructor which takes an `Object` of some sort but you do not pass an object, but a plain `null`.

Comment: Could that be calling to an inherited constructor, or would that look different?

Comment: No it can't @ametren, if you want to do that you have to do it with `super(this)`

Comment: well you can call the parent constructor with super, if Settings extends a class that receives String as an argument, you can use super("somestring")

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if that might have been causing his confusion. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's a constructor that is calling another constructor in the same class.

You presumably have something like this:

```
public class Settings {
    public Settings() {
        this(null);  // <-- This is calling the constructor below
    }

    public Settings(object someValue) {
    }
}
```

Often this pattern is used so that you can offer a constructor with fewer parameters (for ease of use by the callers) but still keep the logic contained in one place (the constructor being called).

Answer (score 4):

It's calling a different constructor inside the Settings class.
Look for another constructor that accepts a single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It call the default constructor passing null as argument ...

Answer (score 1):

> Try to read Overloaded constructor in java and you call constructor who has only one
>   parameter..

.

```
    public Settings() {
        this(null);
    }

   public Settings(Object obj){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Constructor Chaining` in `Java`. By this call you actually invoke overloaded constructor of your class object.  For Example

```
class Employee extends Person {
    public Employee() {
        this("2")  //Invoke Employee's overloaded constructor";
    }

    public Employee(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This basically calls another parameterised constructor in the same class as every one mentioned.

One thing to note here, it will produce an error, if there is no parameterised constructor available.

I do not se any use of passing this() with null value. But can be a tricky question to ask some one. :)