# Overloaded constructor will get null listModel

Tags: java, jlist, defaultlistmodel

i seem to have a rather peculiar issue with my overloaded constructors

in the default constructor AutoFleetServicesMain()

i have

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
list = new JList(listModel);
```

and in the overloaded constructor AutoFleetServicesMain(int i)

i have

```
listModel.addElement(dbh.findAll());
```

according to my output, the default constructor is called before the overloaded one, so i see no reason why listModel is null

although if i add listModel = new DefaultListModel(); to the overloaded constructor, it will run without erroring but i still don't get a list?

Any ideas for what i could do?

Comment: Can you please show the constructors - without that I can't be sure if my answer is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *chain* your constructors, but that doesn't happen automatically. Try adding the following statement to the beginning of your `AutoFleetServicesMain(int)` constructor:

```
this();
```

This will call the default constructor before the subsequent logic. See this post for more examples of constructor chaining: [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Comment: -_- stupid blonde moment, i should have called DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel(); in the global variables instead of DefaultListModel listModel;

Comment: i'm going to say you're correct on this :) but in my project i'm chaining it through another view, thanks for the help though :)