# Java call constructor from constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have a constructor

```
private Double mA;
private Double mB;

Foo(Double a) {
  mA = a;
  mB = a + 10;
}

Foo(Double a, Double b) {
  mA = a;
  mB = b;
  // some logic here
}
```

if I make a call to second constructor like this:

```
Foo(Double a) {
  Double b = a + 10;
  this(a, b);
}
```

than compiler tells me, that constructor should be the first statement. So do I need to copy all logic from the second constructor to first one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why don't you just do `this(a, a+10)` instead?

Note that `this()` or `super()` must be the first statement in a constructor, if present. You can, however, still do logic in the arguments. If you need to do complex logic, you can do it by calling a class method in an argument:

```
static double calculateArgument(double val) {
    return val + 10; // or some really complex logic
}

Foo(double a) {
    this(a, calculateArgument(a));
}

Foo(double a, double b) {
    mA = a;
    mB = b;
}
```

Comment: It is simplified example. In general I can have something like: b = callToFunction(boo(bar(a)))

Comment: @nneonneo: +1 for static `calculateArgument`, non-overridable.

Comment: I think it is not because it is non-overridable, but because you just can't call instance method in this()/super()

Answer (score 6):

If you use `this()` or `super()` call in your constructor to invoke the other constructor, it should always be the first statement in your constructor.

That is why your below code does not compile: -

```
Foo(Double a) {
  Double b = a + 10;
  this(a, b);
}
```

You can modify it to follow the above rule: -

```
Foo(Double a) {
  this(a, a + 10);  //This will work.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Invocation of another constructor must be the first line in the constructor.*

You can call *explicit constructor invocation* like -

```
Foo(Double a) {
  this(a, a+10);
}
```