# Using try catch constructor chain java

Tags: java, constructor, exception, this

I have a class constructor and I need to perform a clone. From what I've read the best choice is to use a copy constructor, just like in C++. However, I've got an issue. If my "regular" constructor throws exceptions and such exceptions aren't even possible in a "copy constructor" how to I implement a try-catch if the first statement must be `this`.

```
public class X
{
   public X() throws MyException
   {
   }

   public X(final X original)
   {
      try {
         this();
      } catch (MyException e)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Is the only option add `throws MyException` to copy constructor?

Comment: Why do you want to call `this()`?

Comment: if you call `this()` you just init a new empty object. if you want a real copy with all values you should add a null-checking to `x(final X original)` and then copy each field from original to `this.<field>`

Comment: "_If my "regular" constructor throws exceptions and such exceptions aren't even possible in a "copy constructor"_" Even if you don't see a way, if a `throws` is present, assume you need to managed it or rethrow the exception. Don't assume an exception defined in a method declaration can't happen. If I need to update your class and I see the exception was defined, I know that this was expected so I can't throw that exception in my updated version without having to worry. The contract was already signed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749218/building-a-copy-constructor-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java call constructor from constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880443/java-call-constructor-from-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Copy all data to a new instance by constructor could look like this:

```
public class X
{
   // some Fields....
   int a, b, c;

   public X() { }

   public X(final X originalX) throws InvalidArgumentException
   {
      if(originalX == null) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("originalX should not be null!");
      }
      this.a = originalX.getA();
      //...
   }
   // getter-setter....
}
```

And it´s called like this in `main()` or where ever else:

```
// x_1 is filles with Data...
X x_2;
try {
    x_2 = new X(x_1);
} catch(InvalidArgumentException ex) {
    LOG.reportError(ex.getMessage());
    x_2 = new X();  // prevent NullPointer for usage afterwards
}
```

Comment: true, but the question is about "catching the exception from `this()`"

Comment: but calling `this()` is doing nothing and shouldn´t be required for his usage.

Comment: Maybe, but this is what your answer should explain ;) What if the constructor have a `init()` statement, what can he do ?