# Does "this" also adapt to function pointers?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, function-pointers

Java has a construct that allows a method to call itself via a "this()" reference. <s>The name of this convention escapes me at the moment.</s>
**EDIT:** Known as *Constructor Delegation* as pointed out below. Will only work on constructors, not methods in general as I have mistaken.

Does C++ with all its pointery goodness provide a reference to itself, but not *specifically* itself?

For example, I have a function with multiple overloads and the like.

```
void DoesSomething(){
    this->(default1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1){
    this->(myValue1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1, int myValue2){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Functions do not have an implicit “this” pointer. So no. Use function name instead.

Comment: Can we say "infinite recursion" ... :)

Comment: Something like this would conflict with the C++ function call operator - `returntype operator()(parameters);`

Comment: It is easy enough to say the next best thing is just to use the function name itself. Are there any benefits to using a keyword this way?

Comment: Note that the particular example here would be more easily handled using the default argument construct `void DoesSomething(int myValue1=default1, int myValue2=default2)`. I assume you are interested in cases where that doesn't work or in understanding the abstract point, eyes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the function name explicitly:

```
void DoesSomething(){
    this->DoesSomething(default1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1){
    this->DoesSomething(myValue1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1, int myValue2){
    //Do stuff
}
```

There is no implicit knowledge of the other function with a given name by context, like you're describing.

Note that in Java, this only works for *constructors*, and is called [Constructor Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java).  It does not handle this for methods in general.

C++11 also adds support for this same concept (as [delegating constructors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement)), though the syntax is different than Java, C#, and other languages with this concept.

For constructors, in C++11, you can write:

```
SomeType() : SomeType(42) {}

SomeType(int arg)
{
   // ...
```

Comment: You might add that constructor chaining in C++ uses a different syntax (but works fundamentally the same as in Java).

Comment: It is mostly for constructors I am thinking about here. It seems as if the C++11 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement) says something about delegating and chaining constructors.

Comment: @JamesKanze Added this reference.

Comment: @DanielPark This does work for constructors - edited to show.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Cheers. I think that will be written on a brain post-it.

Answer (score 1):

That code needs to be modified to:

```
void DoesSomething(){
    this->DoesSomething(default1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1){
    this->DoesSomething(myValue1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1, int myValue2){
    //Do stuff
}
```

or to

```
void DoesSomething(){
    DoesSomething(default1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1){
    DoesSomething(myValue1, default2);
}

void DoesSomething(int myValue1, int myValue2){
    //Do stuff
}
```

because 'this' is not really needed to be explicitely stated in the code.
What does exist in c++ is something called a function object like described here : http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html

Comment: I do like the idea of a "Functor". Could be called code consolidation?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's less confusing to call it a "Functor", because then everyone else will know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

`this` points to the object on which the member function was called. I've seen it most often used when a function needs to return a reference to itself, e.g., `operator()=`; when overloading this operator, you will often also see something like the following to prevent self-assignment

```
foo& foo::operator=(const foo& rhs ){
  if (  this != &rhs ) { 
      //do something
  }
  return *this;
}
```

I think this answers your question??

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd.aspx

Comment: Exception-safe copy-assignment doesn't need a self-reference check.

Comment: Well, I added it to point out another usage of the "this" pointer. But aside from that, it's a simple check that can prevent future headache.

Comment: The places I most commonly see `this` are `return *this`, and for accessing members of a parent class from a derived class template: http://ideone.com/6sFNjb.  If I see a copy assignment with `if (this!=&rhs)`, I immediately assume the function is not exception safe.  (For instance, the sample you linked to is not exception safe)