# Linked List with Generic Types Troubles

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, linked-list

This is giving me some trouble... I don't quite understand what's happening. This is a Data Structures assignment and I have created every class as specified per the instructors UML diagram. This seems like an odd implementation of linked lists. I don't quite understand the constructor in the ListNode class calling another constructor and I don't understand why a counter wasn't specified to keep track of items in the list. I also don't understand the exception class I wrote as the instructor specifies that "the second constructor calls the superclass constructor, and sends the following string as its argument: ( name + “ is empty” );" I just left that empty. I don't quite see how this works. I also completely have no clue how generics work. I did some reading but that didn;t clear up much. I'll post my code and any help would be appreciated. I took the day off work to work on this and I feel like an absolute idiot because this doesn't seem particularly difficult.

The ListNode class:

```
 package linkedLists;

 public class ListNode<T> {

T data;
ListNode<T> nextNode; 

ListNode(T object)
{ 
    this(object, null); 
}

ListNode(T object, ListNode<T> node) 
{ 
    data = object; 
    nextNode = node; 
} 

T getData()
{ 
    return data; 
} 

ListNode<T> getNext() 
{
    return nextNode; 
}
}
```

Here is the List class.

```
  package linkedLists;

  public class List<T>{

      ListNode<T> firstNode;
ListNode<T> lastNode;
String name;

public List()
{
    this("list");
}

public List(String listName)
{
    name = listName;
    firstNode = null;
    lastNode = null;
}

public void insertAtFront(T insertItem)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        ListNode<T> node = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
        firstNode = node;
        lastNode = node;
    }

    else
    {
        ListNode<T> tempNode = firstNode;
        ListNode node = new ListNode(insertItem, tempNode);
        firstNode = node;
    }
}

public void insertAtBack(T insertItem)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        ListNode<T> node = new ListNode<T>(insertItem);
        firstNode = node;
        lastNode = node;
    }

    else
    {
        ListNode<T> tempNode = lastNode;
        ListNode node = new ListNode(insertItem, tempNode);
        lastNode = node;
    }
}

public T removeFromFront() throws EmptyListException
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        throw new EmptyListException("gfy");
    }

    else
    {
        ListNode<T> nr;
        nr = firstNode;

        if(firstNode == lastNode)
        {
            firstNode = null;
            lastNode = null;
        }

        else
        {
            firstNode = firstNode.getNext();
        }

        return nr.getData();
    }
}

public T removeFromBack() throws EmptyListException
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        throw new EmptyListException("gfy");
    }

    else
    {
        ListNode<T> nr;
        nr = lastNode;

        if(firstNode == lastNode)
        {
            firstNode = null;
            lastNode = null;
        }

        else
        {
            ListNode<T> current = firstNode;
            ListNode<T> secondToLast = null;
            int numOfNodes = 0;

            while(current != lastNode)
            {
                secondToLast = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }

            lastNode = secondToLast;
            lastNode.nextNode = null;
        }

        return nr.getData();
    }

}

  public boolean isEmpty( )
   {
    if(firstNode == null)
    return true;

    else
        return false;
}

public void print()
 {
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("List is empty!");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println(firstNode.getData());
        ListNode<T> printNode = firstNode;

        while(printNode != lastNode)
        {
            printNode = printNode.getNext();
            System.out.println(printNode.getData());                
        }
    }

 }



  }
```

The Exception class

```
package linkedLists;

       public class EmptyListException extends RuntimeException
     {
    public EmptyListException()
    {
        this("list");
    }

    public EmptyListException(String name)
    {
    }
      }
```

Finally the main method and test class:

```
// ListTest.java
// ListTest class to demonstrate List capabilities.
import quiz1cs304summer2013kensotak.List;
import quiz1cs304summer2013kensotak.EmptyListException;

public class ListTest 
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      List< Integer > list = new List< Integer >(); // create a List

      // insert integers in list
      list.insertAtFront( -1 );
      list.print();
      list.insertAtFront( 0 );
      list.print();
      list.insertAtBack( 1 );
      list.print();
      list.insertAtBack( 5 );
      list.print();

      // remove objects from list; print after each removal
      try 
      { 
         int removedItem = list.removeFromFront();
         System.out.printf( "\n%d removed\n", removedItem );
         list.print();

         removedItem = list.removeFromFront();
         System.out.printf( "\n%d removed\n", removedItem );
         list.print();

         removedItem = list.removeFromBack();
         System.out.printf( "\n%d removed\n", removedItem );
         list.print();

         removedItem = list.removeFromBack();
         System.out.printf( "\n%d removed\n", removedItem );
         list.print();
      } // end try
      catch ( EmptyListException emptyListException ) 
      {
         emptyListException.printStackTrace();
      } // end catch
     } // end main
     } // end class ListTest
```

The following SHOULD be the output:

```
The list is: -1 
The list is: 0 -1 
The list is: 0 -1 1 
The list is: 0 -1 1 5 

0 removed
The list is: -1 1 5 

-1 removed
The list is: 1 5 

5 removed
The list is: 1 

1 removed
Empty list
```

My output is:

```
-1 
0 
-1 
0 
-1 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at linkedLists.List.print(List.java:146)
    at ListTest.main(ListTest.java:18)
```

Comment: One constructor calling another is called _constructor chaining_, and has been discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/285177/1281433).

Comment: You have a lot of questions and a lot of code. My suggestion would be to ask several trimmed down questions after doing some research (you said you don't understand Generics. That's a good place to start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your print method doesn't even try to print the leading text ("The list is:"), and it prints each item on its own line.

Given that, it looks like the problem is with insertAtBack: the arguments to making your new ListNode are backwards (the new node should come AFTER what was the last node, temp node).

Comment: I see what you're saying Scott. I corrected it and now it functions properly. Thank you very much! Very silly oversight on my part.