# Setter methods or constructors

Tags: java, constructor, setter

So far I have seen two approaches of setting a variable's value in Java. Sometimes a constructor with arguments is used, others setter methods are used to set the value of each variable.

I know that a constructor initializes an instance variable inside a class once a class is instantiated using the `new` keyword.

But when do we use constructors and when do we use setters?

Comment: Those aren't variables, they're (data) members.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You should use the constructor approach, when you want to create a new instance of the object, with the values already populated(a ready to use object with value populated). This way you need not explicitly call the setter methods for each field in the object to populate them.

You set the value using a setter approach, when you want to change the value of a field, after the object has been created.

**For example:-**

```
MyObject obj1 = new MyObject("setSomeStringInMyObject"); // Constructor approach
// Yippy, I can just use my obj1, as the values are already populated
// But even after this I can change the value
obj1.setSomeString("IWantANewValue"); // Value changed using setter, if required.
..
MyObject obj2 = new MyObject();
obj2.setSomeString("setSomeStringNow"); // Setter approach
// values weren't populated - I had to do that. Sad :(
```

And as Axel mentioned, *if you want to create immutable objects, you cannot use setter-methods approach. I won't say everything has to be initialised in the constructor because different approaches exist, like lazy-evaluation which can be used even with immutable objects*.

Comment: +1 and if you want to create immutable objects, you cannot use setter-methods (I won't say everything has to be initialised in the constructor because different approaches exist, like lazy-evaluation which can be used even with immutable objects).

Comment: I'm assuming that we need to have either a constructor or getters and setters in a class. If I'm wrong, could you please tell me of a scenario where we need to use both.

Comment: Let's say your class has 20 odd fields. The application requires you to quickly create a new object of that class with just 5 mandatory fields for object creation. Have a constructor with those 5 fields only and object instantiation is done. Now later in the application, there is a code piece which does some business logic to set/reset the other fields. In that case you'll need your setters for those fields. This is just a simple case and there are many situations where both could be combined. Your assessment of the requirement should be the deciding factor.

Comment: In general, what I think is, the more you are going to manipulate a field, the more likely you'll need it's setters. The fields which are set and forget types, usually go as the constructor parameter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 17):

I think you asked a good question: - But when do we use constructors and when do we use setters?

First, let's start with some concepts. I hope this explanation helps everybody that want to know when to use constructors or setters() and getters() methods (Accessors and Mutators). **Constructors** are similar to **Methods**, however there are few differences between ***constructor*** and ***method*** in java:

1. A ***Constructor*** is used to initialize the state of an object. A  ***Method*** is used to expose behaviour of an object.
2. ***Constructor*** must not have return type. ***Method*** must have return type.
3. ***Constructor*** is invoked implicitly. ***Method*** is invoked explicitly.
4. ***Getters()***, or accessors, are methods that provide access to an object's instance variables. ***Setters()***, or mutators, are methods that provide the caller with an opportunity to update the value of a particular instance variable.

Having this clear, let's think in term of Object Oriented Programming (OOP), to meet the requirement of OOP principals (The *Objects Oriented Programming (OOP)* is constructed over *four major principles*: ***Encapsulation***, ***Data Abstraction***, ***Polymorphism*** and ***Inheritance***.), *Getter()* and *Setter()* methods is the key to achieve this.

Here is a formula that is going to show you what I mean:

> Private fields + Public accessors == Encapsulation;

As you can see based on this formula when we set private fields and use public accesors we are performing encapsulation one of the 4 OOP principals.

Here I am going to provide you two classes, I added comment on it to try to make my code self explaining. Take these classes as a lab on methods with `Customer` and `TestCustomer` [the one with the `main()` method] classes, you can copy the code and run it yourself. Note I used two constructors in order to explain a class having multiple constructors and having public `setters()` and `getters()` methods in order to access private instance variables:

```
package com.exercise.lecture2;

/**
 * 1) Create a Customer class that has the following attributes:
 * name, SSN.
 * 2) This class should have two methods: getName() and getSSN().
 * 3) If the class is instantiated with only a SSN, then give the default name of "John Doe". (HINT: Use two constructors)
 * 4) Also, add a method toString(), that returns a string representation of the customer object (name and SSN concatenated).
 *      Make sure to set this method public.
 * 5) Create a class to test your program (e.g. a class that include the main() method). In your test program, instantiate
 *      three customers and print out the value using toString() method.
 * 
 * @author Samuel M.
 *
 */

//this class is complemented with class  TestLabCustomer.java
public class LabCustomer {

// Private filds: name and socialSecurityNum
    private String name;
    private int socialSecurityNum;
    
    // constructors
    public LabCustomer(String name, int socialSecurityNum) {
        this.name = name;
        this.socialSecurityNum = socialSecurityNum;
    }
    
    /** The keyword 'this' can be used to call a constructor from a constructor,
     * when writing several constructor for a class, there are times when
     * you'd like to call one constructor from another to avoid duplicate code.
     */
    // Account with This() on a second constructor
    public LabCustomer(int socialSecurityNum) {
        this("John Doe", socialSecurityNum); // default name is printed if only the SSN is provided
    }
    
    // Public accessors (getters and setters)
    String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    int getSSN() {
        return socialSecurityNum;
    }
    
    void setSSN(int socialSecurityNum) {
        this.socialSecurityNum = socialSecurityNum;
    }

    
    // instance method
    public String toString() { //overriding the toString() method 
        return ("Customer name: " + getName() + ", SSN#: " + getSSN() ); // concatenating the name and SSN
        
    }
}
```

Here is the test class, the one that has the `main()` method and calling an instance method after instantiating an object of the previews class:

```
package com.exercise.lecture2;

//this class is complemented with class  LabCustomer.java
public class TestLabCustomer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instantiating an object of class LabCustomer and creating three customers objects
        LabCustomer cust1 = new LabCustomer("Juan Melendez", 123457789);
        LabCustomer cust2 = new LabCustomer("Mary Lee", 125997536);
        LabCustomer cust3 = new LabCustomer(124963574); // when instantiating with no "name", the default (John Doe) is printed 
        
        /**
         * Once you've instantiated an object and have an object variable,
         * you can use object variable to call an instance method. 
         *  e.g.:
         *  object variables: cust1, cust2, cust3
         *  call the method toString() using the object variable and dot [.] in order to perform the method call.
         */
        // calling method toString() in class LabCustomer to print customer values
        System.out.println(cust1.toString());
        System.out.println(cust2.toString());
        System.out.println(cust3.toString());

    }

}
```

> *result:*
>
> Customer name: Juan Melendez, SSN#: 123457789
>
> Customer name: Mary Lee, SSN#: 125997536
>
> Customer name: John Doe, SSN#: 124963574

Comment: this is a great example, is there where we can point out perfoming Data Abstraction and  Polymorphism? i would like to see the visibility of those two in code

Answer (score 13):

In simple terms:

Use *constructor* if you think initialization is mandatory before you can use the object.

Use *setter* method when initialization of variable is non-mandatory to use the object.

Refer to documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have an immutable class use constructor otherwise use setters.

Comment: Why? Immutable classes can have setters

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov if an object has setters which mutate state then by definition the object is not immutable, right?

Comment: @vancan1ty Setters can return a new instance of the object instead of mutating it

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I suspect unless this is applied consistently over a codebase this would be a recipe for confusion (definitely the java idiom is that setters (e.g. "setXXX") modify the object).  I see that other people are using "deriveXXX" or copy constructors for the purpose you describe.

Answer (score 3):

We use the approach depending on the scenario.

1. Constructor Approach: We should go ahead with this approach when there are parameters which are mandatory for object's instantiation and we can not construct an object without them.
2. Setter Approach: For optional parameters we can go ahead with the setter approach.

Comment: this makes more sense to me simply to explain to someone

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, i use both of them :)  (since you 9/10 times want to come back and edit something (and that isn't a good practice to make a new instance of it)

I normally make something like this

```java
    public class User {

        private int id;
        private String initials;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
    
        public User() {
            this(0, "", "", "");
        }
    
        public User(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.email = email;
        }
       // Getters and setters should be here
    }
```

And when you want to edit something with it you can just use the setters, (a good thing if you for example is saving your users in an ArrayList, then you can just get the object from the arraylist and just set the field you wanna edit, instead of making a brand new object of it :)

Comment: "Always"? Think about immutables.

Answer (score 2):

Say we have a class, named Counter:

```
public class Counter{
    int count;
    //constructor
    public Counter(int c){
        count = c;
    }
    public void setCounter(int newCounter){
        count = newCounter;
    }
}
```

In the class above, when you want to create a *new* Counter object, you would use a constructor and set the count variable within that. like so:

```
Counter myCounter = new Counter(1);
```

If you want to change the count variable *during runtime*, you would use the setter method:

```
myCounter.setCounter(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of Constructors, When you update fields, you create a new object every time by using *new* keyword.

```
Customer customer = new Customer("Tom", 23, 10000);
```

For example, if you want to update the salary of Tom, you need to write this line again with updated salary, that means memory is wasted.

In case of setter methods you can set individual fields in original object only.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on application domain and purpose of the class in it.

Java beans normally have a no arg constructor and getter/setters for relevant member variables. There are advantages to this approach as Java beans are supported out of the box in many frameworks like Struts and Spring.

A class can also enforce mandatory availability of values by having such variables passed as parameters to a base constructor. And non-mandatory values can be set through other convenience constructors or setter methods.

On the other hand immutable classes can have constructors but require absence methods that modify its state including setters.

Overall, such decisions can be made with consideration to overall design of application, frameworks<sup>1</sup> it runs in, contract it must enforce, etc.

*1 - Although, its recommended that class design should be independent of frameworks. Good frameworks like Spring don't enforce such requirements.*

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two aproaches. Inside the constructor you can invoke the setters of instace variables. Something like:

```
public class TestClass {
    private String someField;

    public TestClass(String someField) {
        setSomeField(someField);
    }

    public String getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    public void setSomeField(String someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    } 
}
```