# How to pass variables between classes?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and have searched through previously asked questions which haven't helped my issue...

How do I pass the int variable age, and the String name, from the main class to the Person class?

```
package engineers;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Engineers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //declaration and ssignment of scanner
        System.out.println("Enter name: "); //name prompt
        String name = scan.next(); //reads name input from user

        System.out.println("Enter age: "); //age prompt
        int age = scan.nextInt(); //reads age input from user

        System.out.println("Pay check amount: "); 
        double salary = scan.nextDouble();
        Person person = new Person();


    }

    private static class Person {
        /**
         * A default constructor
         */
        public Person() {
        }
        /**
         * method for displaying the computation result
         */

       double avgSalary =  40000 * Math.sqrt(Math.exp(0.04295 * age + 0.141) );


        public void showData(int age, double pay){
            System.out.printf( "%s earns $%4.3f for age %3d.\n", name, (pay*Math.sqrt(age)*.15), age); 
        }//end method showData
    }

}
```

Comment: You pass the age in the same way you pass a `String` to `println` or a floating point value to `Math.exp` Your code is full of examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Person constructor like this:

```
 public Person(int age, String name) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
 }
```

And add two fields in your Person class, before your constructor:

```
private int age;
private String name;
```

Then I am assuming you need to use this variables inside the person class, in order to do this, you can do something like this:

```
double avgSalary =  40000 * Math.sqrt(Math.exp(0.04295 * this.age + 0.141) );
```

To reference your variable:

```
public void showData(){
    System.out.printf( "%s earns $%4.3f for age %3d.\n", this.name, (pay*Math.sqrt(this.age)*.15), this.age); 
}//end method showData
```

Finnaly, you need to instantiate your Person object to use it:

```
Person p = new Person(name, age);
```

I would also recommend (since you are learning java), to understand the difference between getters/setters and constructor approach: [Setter methods or constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359548/setter-methods-or-constructors)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
int age;
String name;

class Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
}
```

Or (And)

```
void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to define a constructor with any argument another class may need for the most basic functioning.
A `Person` istance would be initialized with a name and age (even though It would be better to store a birth date and calculate the age against the current date).

To do this, you'd need the class `Person` to look like this:

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    private Date birthdate;

    //Constructor method
    public Person(String n, Date bd){
        name=n;
        birthdate=bd;
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

In the `main()` method, you would then create a new istance of `Person`, after getting anything needed, like this:

```
Person p = new(name, date);
```