# Calling a constructor from method within the same class

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm learning about creating object classes. One of my homework assignment requires that I call the constructor at least once within a method of the same object class. I'm getting an error that says `The method DoubleMatrix(double[][]) is undefined for the type DoubleMatrix`

Here's my constructor:

```
public DoubleMatrix(double[][] tempArray)
{
    // Declaration
    int flag = 0;
    int cnt;

    // Statement

    // check to see if doubArray isn't null and has more than 0 rows
    if(tempArray == null || tempArray.length < 0)
    {
        flag++;
    }

    // check to see if each row has the same length
    if(flag == 0)
    {
        for(cnt = 0; cnt <= tempArray.length - 1 || flag != 1; cnt++)
        {
            if(tempArray[cnt + 1].length != tempArray[0].length)
            {
                flag++;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(flag == 1)
    {
        makeDoubMatrix(1, 1);// call makeDoubMatrix method
    }

}// end constructor 2
```

Here's the method where I try and call the constructor:

```
public double[][] addMatrix(double[][] tempDoub)
{
    // Declaration
    double[][] newMatrix;
    int rCnt, cCnt;

    //Statement

    // checking to see if both are of same dimension
    if(doubMatrix.length == tempDoub.length &&
            doubMatrix[0].length == tempDoub[0].length)
    {
        newMatrix = new double[doubMatrix.length][doubMatrix[0].length];

        // for loop to add matrix to a new one
        for(rCnt = 0; rCnt <= doubMatrix.length; rCnt++)
        {
            for(cCnt = 0; cCnt <= doubMatrix.length; cCnt++)
            {
                newMatrix[rCnt][cCnt] = doubMatrix[rCnt][cCnt] + tempDoub[rCnt][cCnt];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newMatrix = new double[0][0];
        DoubleMatrix(newMatrix)
    }

    return newMatrix;
}// end addMatrix method
```

Can someone point me to the right direction and explain why I'm getting an error?

Comment: add new keyword in else part... else
    {
        newMatrix = new double[0][0];
       new DoubleMatrix(newMatrix)
    }

Comment: @asvikki Thanks, this made the error go away. Can you explain to me why this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Can someone point me to the right direction and explain why I'm getting an error?**

The reason is .. you are not declaring your object correctly. As few answers pointed out, you need to give a keyword called *`new`*. This `new` keyword creates a new object for the class `DoubleMatrix` in Heap Memory.

```
else { newMatrix = new double[0][0]; new DoubleMatrix(newMatrix) }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this()` to call the constructor from [inside another constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java) (or `super()` to call the parent class constructor) but you can't the constructor from another method. Maybe you meant to create a new object? If so, just use `new Object();`. The constructor will be called for the new object.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call constructors from methods, you can call constructors only from other constructors using this or super keywords. You can only call a constructor once, and it has to be the first statement in your constructor body. If you do not call any constructor from a contructore body java compiler will implicitly insert super() statement into the constructor