# What is the purpose of this(); in this context

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
    public Fingerprint(HashMap<String, Integer> measurements) {
        this();
        mMeasurements = measurements;
    }

   public Fingerprint(HashMap<String, Integer> measurements, String map) {
        this(measurements);
        mMap = map;
    }

    public Fingerprint(int id, String map, PointF location) {
        this();
        mLocation = location;
    }

    public Fingerprint(int id, String map, PointF location, HashMap<String, Integer> measurements) {
        this(id, map, location);
        mMeasurements = measurements;
    }
```

what is the purpose of this(); in this context?
Since I have the idea that "this" refers to the fields of the current object. is it the same definition here?

Comment: `this()` calling the noarg constructor `Fingerprint()`.

See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java

Comment: "This" doesn't refer to the fields of the current object, but the current object itself. In a ctor it calls the parameter-less ctor.

Comment: There has to be a no-arg constructor otherwise the code will not compile...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `this();` as if it were a method is the way to invoke another constructor from within a constructor.  You are effectively calling `Fingerprint()`.

Please see the [Java Tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), section "Using this with a Constructor".

Comment: so If I'm calling Fingerprint, I'm not calling another constructor right? is it the same constructor itself?

Comment: No, it's the no-arg ctor, as stated.

Comment: You have code in `Fingerprint()` that you'd also like to call in `Fingerprint(HashMap<String, Integer> measurements)`.  You can call another constructor in this way, from the current constructor.  This also avoids duplication of code in constructors.

Comment: so imagine that I have something like this:     public Fingerprint(HashMap<String, Integer> measurements) {
        mMeasurements = measurements;
    }
the field mMeasurements will never be updated without "this"?

Comment: No, it just makes the constructor `Fingerprint(HashMap<String, Integer> measurements)` do everything that the `FingerPrint()` constructor does (if anything), plus you also have the assignment `mMeasurements = measurements;`.

Comment: @user3170491 "this" refers to the current instance. "this.foo" refers to the foo property of the current instance. "foo" refers to the most local "foo" reference, which may be an instance property, but it could be hidden by a method parameter name, a local variable, etc.