# overload subclass constructor java

Tags: java, constructor-overloading

**Is it possible to overload constructors of a subclass** because I have been racking my brain and I really can't figure it out. Below is the whole of my code so far and the question.

It is school work but its not graded as we have a concepts exam in a few weeks so I'm trying to get through as many exercises as possible.

**Exercise 4 – Overload constructors**:

We have noticed that the majority of the computer labs have a capacity of 20.

Write a new constructor for the ComputerLab class that only has one parameter, the room number, and initialise the capacity to 20. We will have now overloaded the constructor for the ComputerLab class, so that there are  two ways to create instances of the class.

Week7.java:

```
package week7;


public class Week7 {
    /*
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room nonTech = new Room("t12", 25, true);
        System.out.println("nonTech");
        System.out.println(nonTech.getRoomNumber());
        System.out.println(nonTech.getCapacity());
        System.out.println(nonTech.hasProjector());

        ComputerLab tech = new ComputerLab("r12", 10, true, "win7");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("tech");
        System.out.println(tech.getRoomNumber());
        System.out.println(tech.getCapacity());
        System.out.println(tech.hasProjector());
        System.out.println(tech.getOS());

        // hasProjector == false however it will also return true due 
        //to the override method lower down
        LectureRoom mainhall = new LectureRoom("somthing", 100, false);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("mainhall");
        System.out.println(tech.hasProjector());

    }
}

class Room {

    String roomNumber;
    int capacity;
    boolean projection;

    public Room(String rm, int n, boolean p) {
        roomNumber = rm;
        capacity = n;
        projection = p;
    }

    public String getRoomNumber() {
        return roomNumber;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public boolean hasProjector() {
        return projection;
    }
}

class ComputerLab extends Room {
    // RoomNumber, capacity, projection inherited

    private String os;

    public ComputerLab(String rm, int n, boolean p, String os) {
        super(rm, n, p);
        this.os = os;
    }

    public String getOS() {
        return os;
    }

    public void setOS(String update) {
        os = update;
    }

}

class LectureRoom extends Room {
    // RoomNumber, capacity, projection inherited

    public LectureRoom(String rm, int n, boolean p) {
        super(rm, n, p);
    }

    // Overrides Superclass hasProjector
    public boolean hasProjector() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks to me like the following question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a constructor for the `ComputerLab` class that sets the `capacity` to 20:

```
public ComputerLab(String roomNumber) {
    super(roomNumber, 20, false); // is false the correct default value?
    this.os = null; // what is the correct default value?
}
```

`super` here invokes the superclass constructor (`Room` in this case) so you pass to it the argument you want. In this specific case, your `ComputerLab` instance is a `Room` with the room number `roomNumber` (the argument of the new `ComputerLab` constructor), a capacity set to `20` and a projection set to `false`.

Comment: thank you so much Vakh, I really didn't think it was possible.

Comment: can you spare a little bit of time explaining whats going on for me please. why does roomNumber work and not rm when I tried it. thank you again

Comment: I added some information. Whether your name your variable ``rm`` or ``roomNumber`` does not change anything, it is just the name of the variable.