# Does a constructor call create a new instance?

Tags: java

I learned two things:

1. The `new`-operator creates a new instance and then the stated connstructor is executed to initialise that new instance
2. A constructor call (`this()`) creates a new instance.

For my understanding these statements object each other.

For example wouldn't `new Example()` create two instances then, because the `new`-operator creates one and the constructor calls `this()` and creates another? Of course it doesn't but what exactly creates an instance now...?

```
class Example
{
    private boolean _b;

    public Example()
    {
        this(false);
    }

    public Beispiel(boolean b)
    {
        _b = b;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your second point is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second point is incorrect: Invoking `this()` doesn't "create a new instance". Rather, it calls a (usually different) constructor than the one called by `new`.

Calling `new` is what creates the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` inside a constructor to call constructors of the same class with different number of arguments for example:

```
class Example{
    private boolean b;
    public Example(){
        this(false) // you now call public Example(boolean b) to save code istead of    this.b=false
    }
    public Example(boolean b){
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Invoking `this` doesn't create a new instance. Only invoking `new` creates a new instance of the object.

Your syntax `this(argument)` is explicit invocation of a different constructor within the same class.

Such invocation can be done , for instance, to initialize some variables in the object.

See from the Oracle Java tutorials [Using the this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 0):

By calling `this(false)` you do not create a new instance. You just call a constructor within a constructor(the one matching the number of the arguments you are passing), for which i cannot think of any efficient practical use right now, but nevertheless is perfectly valid. Note that, to chain constructors like that, you have to make a new constructor call in the first line of the "parent" constructor.If that makes sense. 
Bottomline; you create one object.
Maybe adding print statements for each different constructor call can help you grasp this thing better.

Also, take a look here: [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java?rq=1)