# Calling super constructor from subclass constructor in Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx, textures, sprite

So, i'm currently working on a game in LibGDX.

I've got a class, "GraphicSprite" that extends Sprite.

```
public class GraphicSprite extends Sprite{

public GraphicSprite(Texture texture){
 //WHERE WOULD I IMPORT THE TEXTURE TO THE SPRITE THAT'S BEING EXTENDED?
 //SHOULD BE SOMETHING LIKE THIS? "this.(classBeingExtended) = new Sprite(texture);
}

}
```

When creating a SPRITE, you have to input some variables.

```
testSprite = new Sprite(TEXTURE HERE);
```

But, I want to create GraphicSprites (which extend Sprite).
So if I do :

```
testGraphicSprite = new GraphicSprite(new Texture(".."));
```

How would I set the texture?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Comment: I don't really understand what that question is asking and how it relates to this :/

Comment: Sorry, I misread that question as calling a constructor on a super class, not a constructor on the same class.  My mistake.  Still, this seems like a question that has surely been answered here before.  Maybe someone can find it and link to it.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, simply call the "super" constructor first.

```
super(texture);
```