# Selection two private constructors in public constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have the following Java-class:

```
public class Permutation {
 ...
private Permutation(int[] cycle){...} //1

private Permutation(int[] inp, int[] outp){...} //2

public Permutation(int[] array, boolean isCycle){ //3
        if(isCycle){
            //creation new Permutation through "1"
        }
        else{
            //splitting on input and output arrays and
            //creation new Permutation through "2"
        }
    }
 ...
}
```

But I when I tried to realize constructor "3", I cought compile error. I know, that I can realize this logic using static method like this:

```
public static Permutation createPermutation(int[] array, boolean isCycle){
    if(isCycle){
        return new Permutation(array);
    }
    //else branch...
}
```

Also I know, that call to `this()` or `super()` must be the first statement in the constructor.
But is it possible to realize exactly **constructor** with architecture "3" (not static creator or something else) in my class? And if it is possible, how can I do that?

UPD: It is not duplicate to [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java) because in my problem I should realize some logic before calling `this()` method and this is the main part of my problems.

Comment: No, that's not possible. But you can create overloaded `private void init(...)` methods with the signatures of your constructor 1 and 2, and then have all 3 constructors invoke these `init` methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Comment: @RobertMoskal While related, I wouldn't exactly call that a duplicate.

Comment: @RobertMoskal, no in [How do I call one constructor from another in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java) this() - is a first statement in constructor, but I want to realize some logic before calling this().

Comment: Dunno, I think the solution is to call this() with the right signature in each if clause.  But I defer to you.

Comment: I suppose since this has to be the first line in the constructor and you can only overcome this limitation with static methods means that it's not possible @Vulcan

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, thanks, init() is good answer for most of the same problems, but in my class some fields declared as final.

Comment: I think I would utilize a *creational pattern* that encapsulate the logic more nicely than a chain of public & private constructors does. Maybe go for a *builder*...?

Comment: Then drop the #1 constructor and change #2: `private Permutation(int[] inp, int[] outp){if (outp == null) { /* code for cycle */ } else { /* code for non-cycle */} ...} //2`. Not that nice but if you want to use constructors and not a static method, and you are using final variables like you describe, then I don't really know another way.