# Can we Call all constructor of a class by creating one object

Tags: java

I have a class which consist of three constructors ,my requiremt is that i want to call all of the constructors using one single object creation.Is it possible??

Lets say

```
 Class A{

        A(int a){
        }

        A(int a,int b){
        }

        A(int a,int b,int c){
        }
```

I want to call all the constructors using one object creation ,how to do that???

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Potentially [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java).

Comment: No. Each constructor creates its own instance. But the constuctors can share code, if that is what you are after. Also, in addition to constructors, there are instance initializer blocks. *All* of those are run in addition to the selected constructor.

Comment: You can refer here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java

Comment: BTW This is possible using Byte code generation, but I am assuming this is not what you had in mind.

Answer (score 5):

Your constructors should be designed in such a way for that. Something like,

```
 Class A{

        A(int a){
            this(a, 0);
        }

        A(int a,int b){
            this(a, b, 0);
        }

        A(int a,int b,int c){
            // All logic here.
        }
```

You can't call multiple constructors from outside to construct a single object.

Comment: Gotta love c# for its shortcut syntax here: `MyClass() : this (0)` etc can also be used to call base class constructors

Comment: @BenKnoble actually default arguments would be nicer in this case ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Class A{
   A(){
     this(10);
     System.out.println("No Arg constructor");
   }
   A(int x){
     System.out.println("Int arg constructor");
   }
}
Class B extends A{
 public static void main (String arg[]){
   B b=new B();

 }
}
```

this() call to it's own overloaded constructor.this() is not add automatically we should add it manually.