# How to overload a GUI constructor?

Tags: java, swing, overloading

In my code I have GUI constructor which extends JDialog as below.

```
public OrdersGUI()
{
  //code for adding SWING components to panels and JDialog.

}
```

Now how do I overload the constructor  with parameters such as (String referenceNo) which will produce the same JDialog as the default constructor without copy/pasting everything from default constructor?

Comment: Put "_everything from default constructor_" in a method and call it from both places? Or store the code in the non default constructor and call that from the default one with a default parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java

Comment: @Sarvadi that is exactly what I was looking for..I just didnt know how put the question that way when I searched for it. Thanks a lot