# why does this keyword in constructor gives different result?

Tags: java, this

I don't Understand why Default constructor is executed after parameterized constructor in this program ?

```
class A{
  int a , b;

  A(){
    this(10,20);
    System.out.println("Inside Default Constructor values:"+a+" "+b);
  }

  A(int a , int b){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
    System.out.println("Inside Parameterized Constructor values:"+a+" "+b);
  }
}

public class thisExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new A();
  }
}
```

This gives output as :

```
Inside Parameterized Constructor values:10 20
Inside Default Constructor values:10 20
```

Comment: it is not. you just log after parameterized executed. actually parameterized is executed within default

Comment: What do you think `this(10,20);` does?

Comment: This looks like a *great* opportunity to use a debugger to step through the code, line by line, and observe how it behaves.  You'll find that each statement tends to execute in the order in which it is invoked.

Comment: Why down vote??

Comment: Related: [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/285177)

Comment: What order did you expect? Why did you expect such order?

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and answers☺

Comment: Before posting this question I expect default  constructor excutes 1st and then parameterized constructor. Now I understand  how it works. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Its clear from your code why its happening

```
A obj = new A();
```

calls your default constructor

```
A(){
    this(10,20);
    System.out.println("Inside Default Constructor values:"+a+" "+b);
}
```

which further calls yours parametrized constructor first `this(10,20);`
so your code prints `Inside Parameterized Constructor values:10 20` first and than it  prints `Inside Default Constructor values:10 20`

Answer (score 1):

The first statement in the default constructor executes the parameterized constructor. You can include the sysout before executing the this(10, 20) and check the behavior.