# How can I pass a value from one constructor to another constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm working with Java. I have a class with 2 constructors. The first constructor takes an int value as a parameter and sets an int variable as that value. The second constructor takes a string and prints it out. The idea is that when I call the first constructor from my main class, it sets an integer value. And when I call the second constructor in the main class, it takes the string representation of int variable of the first constructor and prints it out.

Here's how I made the constructors:

```
public class Test
{
   int val;

   public Test(int x)
   {
      val = x;
      return val; //I know this won't work. So I'm looking for an alternative
   }

   public Test(String y)
   {
      System.out.println("The value is " + y);
   }
}
```

And the main method (in a different class) looks like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Test t1 = new Test(6);
        Test t2 = new Test(String.valueOf(t1)); //This won't work because the first constructor can't return a value
    }
```

So how exactly can I change the contents of the constructors so that I can pass *val* into the 2nd constructor?

Comment: `public Test(int x) { this(String.valueOf(x)); this.val = x; }`

Comment: + from @ernest_k a constructor can't return values.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate -- the OP wants to create `t1`, and then use the value in a subsequent call.

Comment: `int six = 6; Test t1 = new Test(six); Test t2 = new Test(String.valueOf(six)); `

Comment: Not a dupe.  The dupe is a symptom but there are *other* problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Comment: @fantaghirocco:  We've already established that this isn't a dupe of that.

Answer (score 2):

Override `toString()` to return value so when you so `String.valueOf(t1)` it will do the toString() method;

```
public class Test
{
   int val;

   public Test(int x)
   {
      val = x;  
   }

   public Test(String y)
   {
      System.out.println("The value is " + y);
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return String.valueOf(val);
   }
}
```

Comment: Didn't see this one, we said the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are probably actually trying to do is to override the `toString()` method of `Test`.

```
public class Test
{
   int val;

   public Test(int x)
   {
      val = x;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Test:"+val;
   }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Test t1 = new Test(6);
        String s = t1.toString();
        // or this
        System.out.println( t1 ); // prints "Test: 6"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is actually impossible without some changes.

First and foremost, `t1` and `t2` are two separate instances and the values inside of them have no bearing on one another.  So `t1` has `x=6` and `t2` has `x=0` (because of default values).

If you want your second constructor to have a value of `x` that *isn't* 0, then you'll need to pass that in *too*.

```
public Test(int x, String s) {
    super(x);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really want two constructors. It seems like you're wanting to do something like the following:

```
public class Test
{
   int val;

   public Test(int x)
   {
      val = x;
   }

   public void printVal()
   {
      System.out.println("The value is " + val);
   }
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Test t1 = new Test(6);
      t1.printVal();
   }
}
```

Comment: I would not use `printVal()`, but instead override the `toString()` method. In that case, you can do `System.out.println(t1.toString())` to print the value (including the message) to the screen.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Answer by @markspace is a better end result. I was trying to stay closer to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is kinda weird. But this will work even it is kinda weird

```
public class Test {
    private static int val;

    public Test(int x) {
        val = x;
    }

    public Test() {
        System.out.println("The value is " + String.valueOf(val));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test(6);
        Test t2 = new Test();
    }
}
```