# Java and fractions

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I'm trying to add three instance methods to the public interface of class 'Fraction' that all return a 'Fraction' as a result:

add, subtraction and multiplication. is it possible to change it from my current code into instance methods?

I just can't get it to work

Here is my code:

```
class Fraction {
    private Integer numerator;
    private Integer denumerator;

    public Fraction(Integer numerator, Integer denumerator) {

        int gcd = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numerator && i <= denumerator; i++) {
            if (numerator % i == 0 && denumerator % i == 0)
                gcd = i;
        }
        this.numerator = numerator / gcd;
        this.denumerator = denumerator / gcd;
    }

    public Fraction(Integer numerator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denumerator = 1;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return numerator + "/" + denumerator;
    }



    public static Fraction add(Fraction f1,Fraction f2){
        return new Fraction(f1.numerator*f2.denumerator+f2.numerator*f1.denumerator,f1.denumerator*f2.denumerator);
    }
    public static Fraction subtract(Fraction f1,Fraction f2){
        return new Fraction(f1.numerator*f2.denumerator-f2.numerator*f1.denumerator,f1.denumerator*f2.denumerator);
    }
    public static Fraction mul(Fraction f1,Fraction f2){
        return new Fraction(f1.numerator*f2.numerator,f1.denumerator*f2.denumerator);
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        final Fraction HALF = new Fraction(1, 2);
        final Fraction THREE_FIFTH = new Fraction(3, 5);
        System.out.println(HALF.add(HALF, THREE_FIFTH).toString());
        System.out.println(THREE_FIFTH.subtract(HALF, THREE_FIFTH).toString());
        System.out.println(HALF.mul(HALF, THREE_FIFTH).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear how a constructor and the `toString()` method can interact as you're mentioning. Doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Updated my question. I was just trying to make changes in my constructor to make this to work.

Comment: just have `public class Fraction(int numerator) { this(numerator, 1); }`, no?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Just write another constructor?

Comment: @Sweeper I did. Check my code for an updated answer

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Do it as I mentioned in my comment and as Jon Skeet does in the duplicate question.

Comment: edit: as Jon Skeet does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285184/522444)

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is it possible to change these into  instance methods, though?

Comment: @UMLtotallydistilled: yes of course it is. The devil is in the details. You need to tell specifically what you're trying to do and show how you're trying to do it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I basically tried to add 3 methods like this with returning the numenator and denumerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public static Fraction add(Fraction f1,Fraction f2){
>   return new Fraction(f1.numerator*f2.denumerator+f2.numerator*f1.denumerator,
>                       f1.denumerator*f2.denumerator);
> }
> ```

is a class method (because of the `static` it does not need an instance to call "on").

Making it instance method would look like

```
public Fraction add(Fraction other){
  return new Fraction(this.numerator*other.denumerator+other.numerator*this.denumerator,
                      this.denumerator*other.denumerator);
}
```

of course you do not actually need to write the `this`s there, just they emphasize that `f1` became the current object, and `f2` became the single argument.

Then you could use it as

```
Fraction HALF = new Fraction(1, 2);
Fraction THREE_FIFTH = new Fraction(3, 5);
System.out.println(HALF.add(THREE_FIFTH));
```

without repeating `HALF` (like `HALF.add(HALF,THREE_FIFTH)` in the original code).

Side comment: class methods (`static` stuff) can be referred via the name of the class, your original code would be more conventionally called in the form `Fraction.add(...)`:

```
System.out.println(Fraction.add(HALF,THREE_FIFTH));
```

(`System.out.println()` knows that it should call `toString()` so you do not actually need to do that yourself)

Comment: @UMLtotallydistilled yes, `subtract()` and `mul()` could be made into instance methods in the same way as shown with `add()`