# Multiple class builders, with different parameters

Tags: java, class, build, constructor

I have several mandatory parameters and some which aren't. So the basic builder I made is with all the parameters:

```
public MyObject(int field1, int field2)
    {
     this.field1 = field1;
     this.field2 = field2;
    }
```

But `field2` is not mandatory. So I added another builder:

```
public MyObject(int field1)
    {
     new MyObject(field1, 0);
    }
```

So the problem here is the `new` part. However, without the `new` I get an error. I tried adding `return`, but still an error.

Basically, I don't want to write another builder, I want to use the same one as before. Simply, to call it with default values for the non-mandatory parameters. But I must add `new`, and then I am creating a new instance of the class, which is not what I wanted!

The reasoning behind calling the existing builder is that there are many function inside the builder, not just `this.blahblah= blahblah`, so I don't want to write the same code twice. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Comment: You need to replace `new MyObject(field1, 0);` with `this(field1, 0);`

Comment: Yes, thanks. Feels so simple :)

Comment: These are constructors, not builders. The builder pattern is something different.