# call one constructor from another constructors in one class

Tags: constructor, language-agnostic

I've encountered the following question online.

If we call one constructor from another in a class, what will happen?

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Well, in C++, there are copy constructors that use some other constructors, to clone an object's data from other object. So that basically does what you're questioning here. You can look into that.

Comment: Assuming C++11: You can read about delegating Constructors [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor).

Comment: The question is too broad to cover all languages.

Comment: Why is this tagged inheritance?

Comment: @Fihop did it solve your interview question

Answer (score 4):

in java also its possible with the power of the `this` keyword. check out the example given below.

```
public class A {

    public A() {
        //this("a");
        System.out.println("inside default Constructor");
    }

    public A(String a){
        this();
        System.out.println("inside Constructor A");
    }

}
```

This concept is called **constructor chaining**. If it's c# i found this saying it's possible [Is nesting constructors (or factory methods) good, or should each do all init work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284896/is-nesting-constructors-or-factory-methods-good-or-should-each-do-all-init-wo)

Comment: no @leppie it says **assume**, thats y i just gave my 0.02$ on the various oop language

Comment: that was me. The question is too broad to cover all languages.

Answer (score 1):

This example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn387583.aspx) clarifies it

To add delegating constructors, `constructor (. . .) : constructor (. . .)` syntax is used.

```
class class_a {
public:
    class_a() {}
    // member initialization here, no delegate
    class_a(string str) : m_string{ str } {}

    // can’t do member initialization here
    // error C3511: a call to a delegating constructor shall be the only member-initializer
    class_a(string str, double dbl) : class_a(str) , m_double{ dbl } {}

    // only member assignment
    class_a(string str, double dbl) : class_a(str) { m_double = dbl; }
    double m_double{ 1.0 };
    string m_string;
};
```

Read answers from [Can I call a constructor from another constructor (do constructor chaining) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308276/call-constructor-from-constructor-in-c) too.

Comment: Just another reason why I steer clear of C++. Syntax is way too complex.

Comment: @leppie Yes, it is, if you compare with counterparts like Java

Comment: i have to agree with @leppie syntax in java is pretty decent